# Fetching records from Cust table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
1   abc_chg
2   a_dhj
3   axc_kk
4   sdsd
```

I have four records in the table `Cust`. I want to get only those records which contain an underscore.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean *contain an underscore* or consist entirely of underscores*? I think that you mean the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) with wildcards on this way:

```
Select *
from   Cust
where  Field LIKE '%[_]%';
```

Comment: underscore in a `LIKE` expression is a wildcard that will match any single character so this will return all non-null values.

Comment: ` LIKE '%[_]%'`